# Node.js garbage collection and synchronized objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, garbage-collection

This is a little bit tricky to explain, but I'll give it a try:

In a node.js server application I would like to deal with data objects that can be used in more than one place at once. The main problem is, that these objects are only referred to by an object id and are loaded from the database.

However, as soon as an object is already loaded into one scope, it should not be loaded a second time when requested, but instead the same object should be returned.

This leads me to the question of garbage collection: As soon as an object is no longer needed in any scope, it should be released completely to prevent having the whole database in the server's memory all the time. But here starts the problem:

There are two ways I can think of to create such a scenario: Either use a global object reference (which prevents any object from being collected) or, really duplicate these objects but synchronize them in a way that each time a property in one scope gets changed, inform the other instances about that change.

Again, therefore each instance would have to register an event handler, which in turn is pointing back to that instance thus preventing it from being collected again.

Did anyone come up with a solution for such a scenario I just didn't realize? Or is there any misconception in my understanding of the garbage collector?

What I want to avoid is manual reference counting for every object in the memory. Everytime when an object is being removed from any collection, I would have to adapt the reference count manually (there is even no destructor or "reference decreased" event in js)

Comment: So… you want a cache. You can limit the number of items in the cache, discarding the least recently used ones. You can also remove items ahead of time if you know you won’t need them anymore, but that’s not something that can be done automatically.

Comment: A "cache" is not exactly the right concept, it should be that no object gets loaded twice, once it is already in the memory. In a cache with a limited size, this would not be guaranteed. Items that are removed from the cache (but possibly still referenced somewhere else), _would_ be loaded twice. And of course I could keep track of any deletion myself, but I believe there must be a more elegant way, because as soon as you forget to decrease your reference counter when deleting an object somewhere, your memory leak is there. Exactly what a GC should avoid.

Comment: What determines when you won’t need to reference an object anymore, then? When it’s not present in any “collection”? What’s a collection?

Comment: As soon as an object is released from any scope it was used in, it could be collected (also the data) and being reloaded as soon as it is needed again somewhere. The problem is that I want to avoid different versions of the same object in memory, thus, only one instance. The second advantage is that every object using this data object would be aware of the latest updated version (because they all use the same object rather than an own copy of it). After there is no true parallel execution (or better: scheduling) in node.js, race conditions are not a concern

Comment: Have you considered using something like Redis? What you are describing sounds quite complex to implement and would likely be very error prone.

Comment: @Psi: Okay, that didn’t remotely answer the question of when it’s safe to assume an object won’t need to be fetched anymore.

Comment: @AlecFenichel Thank you for the tip, but I am not trying to build a database. I am trying to build a server application for websockets that also has  to deal with data, but mainly has to do other jobs. However, it should use only one version of a specific type of objects. Of course, I could keep them all in memory, but the more objects there are, the more likely the app is to crash

Comment: @Ryan An object can be fetched anytime, sorry, I understood "when an object can get released". And a "collection" is a pretty well defined term.

Comment: @Psi: If you don’t know when an object can be fetched in the future and you have a hard requirement to only have one instance of it ever, you can never release it. It doesn’t sound like you necessarily really have that requirement, though… can you use the aforementioned limited cache and fetch the object from cache every time you want to read from or modify it? Sorry to ask about “collections”, but the way you were talking about manual reference counting seemed to imply you could somehow know when an object would no longer be required.

Comment: @Ryan The problem is that I have no way of knowing when to remove an object from the cache (except for manual ref counting). If I remove an object from a cache but anywhere there is still a reference to it, the next one trying to fetch the object will create a duplicate in memory. And I could release it, if I was aware of when there is no reference to the object anymore. Unluckily there is no way to access the GCs internal ref counter.

Comment: @Psi: Yes, the idea is to make it so there are no lasting references except in the cache. So rather than `let obj = cache.get(id); obj.x = 5; await …; obj.y = 6;`, you have `cache.update(id).x = 5; await …; cache.update(id).y = 6;`. Or more explicitly, `cache.update(id, {x: 5})`. Like a database.

Comment: @Psi One of the most common use cases of Redis is as a cache between an application and a database. You would keep using your database exactly how you currently do. When you need an object, you get it from Redis. If it isn't there, you put the object in Redis and then use it. Not sure what you are trying to do, but Redis is frequently used as a way to share states between multiple application servers. Your use case sounds quite similar.

Comment: @Ryan Now I get your point. This is indeed a possible way, I will think about that.

Comment: @AlecFenichel Thank you very much, but then it's easier to store the data within the application

Comment: @AlecFenichel - I don't see the value of Redis in this case.  It doesn't do the ref cnting of a single object that the OP needs and if it was used for access from multiple processes (one of the main values of Redis), then they wouldn't actually be shared live objects either since a Javascript object lives in only one process.

Comment: To be honest, in fact this is halfway an own garbage collection. It seems to be the only solution to this problem, but was more or less what I wanted to avoid. Anyway thank you all for your help

Comment: @jfriend00 I'm not sure the use case needed by the OP. But I'd be surprised if implementing a custom garbage collection system is a good idea. I was just trying to promote thinking of other solutions. "Bad programmers worry about the code. Good programmers worry about data structures and their relationships." - Linus Torvalds

Comment: @AlecFenichel - Well, a cache that caches only objects that are "in use" and always caches an object in use needs to know when they are still in use or no longer in use.  There's no way around that given the requirements the OP laid out.  If we understood the entire problem from start to finish, we might be able to offer a better overall solution, but we weren't given that level of understanding so all we can do is offer a solution that fits the requirements we were given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `weak` module, I implemented a `WeakMapObj` that works like we originally wanted `WeakMap` to work.  It allows you to use a primitive for the key and an object for the data and the data is retained with a weak reference.  And, it automatically removes items from the map when their data is GCed.  It turned out to be fairly simple.

```
const weak = require('weak');

class WeakMapObj {
    constructor(iterable) {
        this._map = new Map();
        if (iterable) {
            for (let array of iterable) {
                this.set(array[0], array[1]);
            }
        }
    }

    set(key, obj) {
        if (typeof obj === "object") {
            let ref = weak(obj, this.delete.bind(this, key));
            this._map.set(key, ref);
        } else {
            // not an object, can just use regular method
            this._map.set(key, obj);
        }
    }

    // get the actual object reference, not just the proxy
    get(key) {
        let obj = this._map.get(key);
        if (obj) {
            return weak.get(obj);
        } else {
            return obj;
        }
    }

    has(key) {
        return this._map.has(key);
    }

    clear() {
        return this._map.clear();
    }

    delete(key) {
        return this._map.delete(key);
    }
}
```

I was able to test it in a test app and confirm that it works as expected when the garbage collector runs.  FYI, just making one or two objects eligible for garbage collection did not cause the garbage collector to run in my test app.  I had to forcefully call the garbage collector to see the effect.  I assume that would not be an issue in a real app.  The GC will run when it needs to (which may only run when there's a reasonable amount of work to do).

---

You can use this more generic implementation as the core of your object cache where an item will stay in the `WeakMapObj` only until it is no longer referenced elsewhere.

---

Here's an implementation that keeps the map entirely private so it cannot be accessed from outside of the `WeakMapObj` methods.

```
const weak = require('weak');

function WeakMapObj(iterable) {
    // private instance data
    const map = new Map();

    this.set = function(key, obj) {
        if (typeof obj === "object") {
            // replace obj with a weak reference
            obj = weak(obj, this.delete.bind(this, key));
        }
        map.set(key, obj);

    }

    // add methods that have access to "private" map
    this.get = function(key) {
        let obj = map.get(key);
        if (obj) {
            obj = weak.get(obj);
        }
        return obj;
    }

    this.has = function(key) {
        return map.has(key);
    }

    this.clear = function() {
        return map.clear();
    }

    this.delete = function(key) {
        return map.delete(key);
    }

    // constructor implementation    
    if (iterable) {
        for (let array of iterable) {
            this.set(array[0], array[1]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Very nice! Much more elegant than dealing with manual refcounting.

Comment: @Psi - Yeah, that `weak` module is pretty cool and it seems to work just great in node.js.  One wonders why the language itself doesn't have this type of `weakMap`.  I see lots of reason to use something like this.

Comment: That was why I asked this question, I really could not believe that there is no built-in functionality to do this. For the GC: It only runs when some conditions are met (such as memory peaks, time), and therefore you would have to wait for about 10-20 minutes for the GC to kick in. Forcing the collection is a better way of testing. However, I don't recommend to use the GC in production code, but for testing purposes it is quite useful

Comment: @Psi - I made an update to this implementation to override `.get()` so that it fetches the actual object, not just the weak proxy. This, I think, is required for use because now when someone calls `cache.get(id)`, it returns a live reference to the actual object (which keeps it from being GCed while in use). Without this override, it just returned the weak proxy which did not keep the original from being GCed while you were trying to use its proxy which could easily cause problems. A full implementation would also need to do this same override on `.entries()`, `.forEach()`. and `.values()`.

Comment: Right, didn't think about that but it's obvious

Comment: Note that this simple implementation does not fully support `.entries()`, `.forEach()`. and `.values()` or any ES6 syntax that would use an iterator like `for/of`.  They could be used in fully synchronous code in some situations, but could run into some trouble in async code because they return proxies for the real objects which don't prevent the real objects from getting GCed.  This is a reason that the built-in `weakMap()` does not allow iteration and iteration should probably be prevented here too.

Comment: @Psi - I changed the implementation to NOT support iteration (just like a `weakMap`) because of the problems that can cause.  The implementation no longer inherits from `Map` because that exposes iteration.  Instead, the instance data contains a `Map` for internal use only.  I think this is cleaner, safer, general-purpose implementation.

Comment: Another improvement: Use `weak.isDead` to unambiguously detect whether a ref is dead. Also, this cache should work more like an unsorted map, a simple underlying expando (just a regular, empty object) should do the trick. AFAIK, the names upon objects are looked up in O(1) in v8 (used by node.js).

Comment: @Psi - I don't think there's any reason for `isDead()` because the callback immediately removes it from the `Map` so there should never be any dead items in there.

Comment: Indeed, that's true. I'm still thinking too much about parallel execution which doesn't happen in node.

Comment: @Psi - What advantage do you think a plain object would have over using a `Map`?  A plain object both requires keys that can be uniquely converted to strings with `.toString()` and requires extra code to avoid collisions with existing object property names such as `hasOwnProperty`.  The `Map` can use any type for a key, thus appears to be more flexible and simpler.

Comment: I was also considering the problems arising with name collisions, but for my key type (an objectID), this is not a big deal. A `Map` can use any type of key, that's true, but as I said, you are inheriting a lot of functionality you have to "throw away" afterwards (meaning: hiding, avoiding, programming around). I didn't check whether there is a kind of unordered list in node yet, but using that class would be more suitable I believe. However, nice job anyway.

Comment: @psi - If you compare my current code using a `Map` (which is fully `Map`-safe) to the same functionality using a plain object, I don't think you're going to find the object implementation is any simpler, in fact it may need a little more code because of name collision avoidance.  In my experience `Map` and `Set` objects are a lot cleaner way of doing things than the old hack of using a plain Object.

Comment: That's true, using dedicated classes is of course the cleaner way. I'm just not sure if a `Map` is the perfect choice, but I guess that's also kind of subjective. Your class is nonetheless better for that kind of problem than anything that is offered by native JS anyway

Comment: @Psi - Well you need to associate a key with a value efficiently and that's what `Map` does.  Yes, it has a little more functionality than that built-in, but it does no harm to not use that functionality.  The only rationale I could think of for switching to a plain object and adding name collision logic would be if you could prove that the plain object was meaningfully faster and there was no value to having a more generic implementation (for other uses) that didn't require strings as keys.

Comment: @Psi - One other improvement I've been contemplating is to truly hide the internal `Map` from public access (make it a truly private instance variable) so there's no backdoor way for anyone else to get to your objects except through the `get()` method.  The `_map` property name designates it as an "internal-use" only property, but obviously it is still accessible if someone wanted to access it.  If it's all your own code using it, then there's no issue with that, but if this was used in an API or something like that, then you might want to truly prevent outside access to the internal storage.

Comment: I always try to make my classes' interface as clean as possible, even if I only use them myself, I never know when I want to use them again (and maybe forget about every aspect of their internal structure) or hand them over to someone else. However, it's nice to see that I'm not the only one interested in a "true" weakmap implementation.

Comment: @Psi - I added an alternate implementation that keeps the internal `Map` entirely private so it cannot be messed with.

Comment: Thank you very much, very goob job. But don't get me wrong: I did not expect you to tweak the class until it meets my requirements. The answer you provided was perfectly matching my question in the first place.

Comment: @Psi - I'm tweaking for my own benefit, but I think I'm done now.  I hope to use this myself later and perhaps refer other questions on stack overflow to it.

Comment: Then it's fine for me :) I started feeling bad for causing you to put in all this effort.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a job for a `Map` object used as a cache storing the object as the value (along with a count) and the ID as the key.  When you want an object, you first look up its ID in the `Map`.  If it's found there, you use the returned object (which will be shared by all).  If it's not found there, you fetch it from the database and insert it into the `Map` (for others to find).

Then, to make it so that the `Map` doesn't grow forever, the code that fetches something from the `Map` would also need to release an object from the `Map`.  When the useCnt goes to zero upon a release, you would remove an object from the `Map`.

This can be made entirely transparent to the caller by creating some sort of `cache` object that contains the `Map` and has methods for getting an object or releasing an object and it would be entirely responsible for maintaining the `refCnt` on each object in the `Map`.

Note: you will likely have to write the code that fetches it from the DB and inserts it into the `Map` carefully in order to not create a race condition because the fetching form the database is likely asynchronous and you could get multiple callers all not finding it in the `Map` and all in the process of getting it from the database.  How to avoid that race condition depends upon the exact database you have and how you're using it.  One possibility is for the first caller to insert a place holder in the `Map` so subsequent callers will know to wait for some promise to resolve before the object is inserted in the `Map` and available to them to use.

Here's a general idea for how such an `ObjCache` could work.  You call `cache.get(id)` when you want to retrieve an item.  This always returns a promise that resolves to the object (or rejects if there's an error getting it from the DB).  If the object is in the cache already, the promise it returns will be already resolved.  If the object is not in the cache yet, the promise will resolve when it has been fetched from the DB.  This works even when multiple parts of your code request an object that is "in the process" of being fetched from the DB.  They all get the same promise that is resolved with the same object when the object has been retrieved from the DB.  Every call to `cache.get(id)` increases the `refCnt` for that object in the cache.

You then call `cache.release(id)` when a given piece of code is done with an object.  That will decrement the internal `refCnt` and remove the object from the cache if the `refCnt` hits zero.

```
class ObjCache() {
    constructor() {
        this.cache = new Map();
    }
    get(id) {
        let cacheItem = this.cache.get(id);
        if (cacheItem) {
            ++cacheItem.refCnt;
            if (cacheItem.obj) {
                // already have the object
                return Promise.resolve(cacheItem.obj);
            }
            else {
                // object is pending, return the promise
                return cacheItem.promise;
            }
        } else {
            // not in the cache yet
            let cacheItem = {refCnt: 1, promise: null, obj: null};
            let p = myDB.get(id).then(function(obj) {
                // replace placeholder promise with actual object
                cacheItem.obj = obj;
                cacheItem.promise = null;
                return obj;
            });
            // set placeholder as promise for others to find
            cacheItem.promise = p;
            this.cache.set(id, cacheItem);
            return p;

        }
    }
    release(id) {
        let cacheItem = this.cache.get(id);
        if (cacheItem) {
            if (--cacheItem.refCnt === 0) {
                this.cache.delete(id);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I just read about `WeakMap`s and I believe, they are not exactly a solution for what I am trying to do. A `WeakMap` stores an object (weakly referenced) as the key and is able to remove the value when the object gets collected. However, this would be the same if I just stored the data in the object itself. Unfortunately, `WeakMap` does not work the other way 'round. `Number`s or `String`s are not allowed for a key in the `WeakMap`

Comment: @Psi - You're right.  A `weakMap` isn't quite right for how you've describe your task.  But, you could make a regular `Map` work for it (I've revised my answer as such), but you'd have to do manual refCnt ing as you fetch, use and release an object.

Comment: True, but now it is exactly what I wrote in my edit of the question: I need to do manual reference counting (i.e. every time an object gets released from any scope, I need to inform it about that happening). I hoped there was another way around this, because this is not why I am using javascript, to deal with manual reference counting again.

Comment: @Psi - I don't know any other way.  I've tried to figure out a way to make a `weakMap`  work for you, but I don't see how.  I added to my answer an outline of an `ObjCache()` that handles race conditions.  I assumed a place holder for your database operation to retrieve the object when it's not in the cache and used promises to handle the race condition.

Comment: Thank you very much, I really appreciate your effort. However, to know when to release an object I must be sure that no other reference is still alive. So every object referencing that object needs to be aware of when it gets removed.

Comment: @Psi - Not exactly.  In the example I provided, you just need each local piece of code using an object to call `cache.release(id)` when it's done with its own copy of an object.  The cache will handle removing it from the cache itself when the internal `refCnt` hits zero inside of the `cache.release(id)` implementation.  Since you show none of the code that uses these objects, we can't really advise you on that implementation.

Comment: I know what you want to do here. It's an implementation of the cache mentioned by Ryan in the comments to my question. The idea is not so bad, I hoped there was a more elegant solution to this (a kind of reverse WeakMap) to remove the need to worry for references or a cache that keeps data it does not need and throws away data that could still be in use and has to be fetched again, and so all.

Comment: @Psi - Yeah, I was hoping the `weakMap` could be used here too, but I can't see a way to use it.

Comment: After hours of looking around: https://www.npmjs.com/package/weak, maybe this will help. Perhaps I could build the cache/lookup-table using this

Comment: @Psi - That's interesting.  I don't quite grok how you'd use it to achieve your objective though.

Comment: My idea: Keep a weak reference in a custom `Map`. There is an event that informs you about the garbage collection. I'm not 100% sure if this is going to work, still reading.

Comment: @Psi - Might work.  You'd have to figure out how to get the relevant ID from within the callback (probably could do so via a closure) so you can remove that item from the `Map`, but have to make sure the object itself is not available from the closure or that could prevent GC.

Comment: That's true. Maybe it is possible by scoping. Playing around. Maybe I found a solution: If an object got GC'ed, the object is empty afterwards. That means the data is gone from memory (I only have the ID referencing nothing). If it is accessed but empty -> reload

Comment: Or, when you get the callback, you remove it from the `Map` entirely.

Comment: Yep, but as you pointed out correctly: That involves messing around with figuring out what object really got collected. At the moment I'm fine with this solution (if it works).

Answer (score 1):

Ok, for anyone who faces similar problems, I found a solution. jfriend00 pushed me towards this solution by mentioning `WeakMaps` which were not exactly the solution themselves, but pointed my focus on weak references.

There is an npm module simply called [`weak`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/weak) that will do the trick. It holds a weak reference to an object and safely returns an empty object once the object was garbage collected (thus, there is a way to identify a collected object).

So I created a class called `WeakCache` using a `DataObject`:

```
class DataObject{

    constructor( objectID ){
        this.objectID = objectID;
        this.dataLoaded = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
            loadTheDataFromTheDatabase(function(data, error){ // some pseudo db call
                if (error)
                {
                    reject(error);
                    return;
                }

                resolve(data);
            }); 
        });
    }

    loadData(){
        return this.dataLoaded;
    }   
}

class WeakCache{

    constructor(){
        this.cache = {};
    }

    getDataObjectAsync( objectID, onObjectReceived ){
        if (this.cache[objectID] === undefined || this.cache[objectID].loadData === undefined){ // object was not cached yet or dereferenced, recreate it

            this.cache[objectID] = weak(new DataObject( objectID )function(){
                // Remove the reference from the cache when it got collected anyway
                delete this.cache[this.objectID];
            }.bind({cache:this, objectID:objectID});
        }

        this.cache[objectID].loadData().then(onObjectReceived);
    }

}
```

This class is still in progress but at least this is a way how it could work. The only downside to this (but this is true for all database-based data, pun alert!, therefore not such a big deal), is that all data access has to be asynchronous.

What will happen here, is that the cache at some point may hold an empty reference to every possible object id.

Comment: FYI, one simple way to deal with the empty references would be to just use a `setInterval()` timer that runs every hour or so and removes any elements that contain empty references.  As long as that code to remove them is all synchronous, it won't cause any possible race condition.  But, it is likely possible to use the weak callback to clean it up real-time too.

Comment: I was thinking in a similar way, but using the callback when an object gets freed, does help as well. You can bind the objectID to the callback function which then just removes the objectID which was the key in the lookup table.

Comment: I was just reading in the `weak` reference that you have to be very careful with the callback to not accidentally catch the object itself in scope of the callback because if you do, it will never be garbage collected since it's still technically "reachable" by live code.  They recommend using high level scoped callback functions only.  Your mention of using `.bind()` on a top level callback would be a nice way to capture the ID without any danger of capturing the object itself in scope.

Comment: Exactly. I am running my tests with an advanced implementation of what you see here, and what I currently can verify is that it is working perfectly. Luckily, using --expose_gc you can force the gc to cleanup, very good way to test the behavior

Comment: See the `WeakMapObj` class I put in a new answer.  I also had to use `--expose-gc` to be able to run `global.gc()` to test it, and it does work.  Pretty cool.